# Sample from a normal distribution using parameters from an ordered dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, random

I need help with creating a function that samples from a random uniform distribution with parameters defined in an ordered dictionary and returns a dictionary with parameter names as keys, using any random seed.

```
parameter=OrderedDict([('a', (100.0, 0.0)), ('b', (90.0, 5.0))])
```

NB: `(100.0, 0.0)` are mean and std deviation respectively

Expected return: `{'a': 105.46565, 'b': 90}`

Thanks

Comment: let me better understand your question, you want to sample from a normal distribution with parameters from the ordered dictionary? how is a zero variance normal distribution centered in `100` going to ever give you `105.46`?

Comment: why not just iterate in the list and pick the key-values pairs and put them in a dict.? also would like to hear your implementation for this

Comment: Filippo let me make it easier for u buddy......                 def f(orderedDict): perform uniform distribution using the value in the tuple, last return a dictionary. About the  105.46 u said, i was intending to show you the format of the return not the exact value. Hope u got it now. Cheers!

Comment: Bekry consider editing your question with a more plausible expected result then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import random

parameter = OrderedDict([('a', (100.0, 0.0)), ('b', (90.0, 5.0))]) 
samples = {}

for k, (mu, sigma) in parameter.items(): 
    samples[k] = random.normalvariate(mu, sigma)

>>> print(samples)
{'a': 100.0, 'b': 89.02621974794464}
```

Comment: Filippo you have almost done it, just import only random and use random.normalvariant(mu, sigma) instead of np.random.normal(mu,sigma). Cheers!